# NodeJs destroy this object?

Tags: node.js

I have a module that stores all connected TCP sockets. When a socket is closed I have a function that should remove the socket. For some reason the socket is not always removed and I get this error:

> Error: This socket has been ended by the other party

My module:

```
module.exports = Agent;
var Agents = []; // Stores all sockets

// This fires when a new socket is created
Agent.prototype.subscribe = function (server, socket) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;
    this.id = socket.name;
    this.request = socket.request;

    Agents.push(this);
}

// This fires when a socket is closed
Agent.prototype.onclose = function (reason) {
    console.log('[Removing agent socket with reason: %s]', reason);

    console.log(Agents.length);
    Agents.splice(Agents.indexOf(this), 1);
    console.log(Agents.length);    
};
```

Im thinking that I might be removing the socket the wrong way? Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to give identifiers to your socket so that you debug log clearly states which ones are added and removed. There may be cases when you send a message to a socket, but since this is async, the remote can close the socket in between, so you have a reference out there to a closed socket.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. Could I use this.id?

Comment: indeed you could add an attribute on your created socket objects ; 'id' seems a bit too generic as it might collide with a reserved keyword ;